# Oracle get previous day records

Tags: oracle, datetime

Ok I think I'm getting the previous year instead of the previous day, but I need to previous day.

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') - 1 FROM Dual
```

I'm comparing it to a datetime stamp in this format and wish to get all the rows from the previous day.

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

So I'm trying something like this

```
SELECT field,datetime_field 
FROM database
WHERE datetime_field > TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') - 1
```

Comment: Assuming datetime_field is of DATE type, your code should work. However, you're converting a date to a string and back to a date for no reason. Use shahkalpesh's answer.

Comment: The reason for the conversion is I only want the DATE, not the DATE/TIME

Answer (score 40, accepted):

how about sysdate?

```
SELECT field,datetime_field 
FROM database
WHERE datetime_field > (sysdate-1)
```

Comment: SYSDATE adds the time, I just want the date

Comment: TRUNC() nice! Didn't think to use this

Comment: trunc(current_date) works also. current_date = Oracle session time zone; sysdate = Oracle Server date and time.

Comment: If you Need records created today try this...    SELECT field,datetime_field FROM database WHERE Trunc(datetime_field) = Trunc(sysdate)

Answer (score 9):

You can remove the time part of a date by using `TRUNC`.

```
select field,datetime_field 
  from database
 where datetime_field >= trunc(sysdate-1,'DD');
```

That query will give you all rows with dates starting from yesterday. Note the second argument to `trunc()`. You can use this to truncate any part of the date.

If your datetime_fied contains `'2011-05-04 08:23:54'`, the following date will be returned

```
trunc(datetime_field, 'HH24') => 2011-05-04 08:00:00
trunc(datetime_field, 'DD')   => 2011-05-04 00:00:00
trunc(datetime_field, 'MM')   => 2011-05-01 00:00:00
trunc(datetime_field, 'YYYY') => 2011-00-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution and understanding

**To answer the question:**

```
SELECT field,datetime_field 
FROM database
WHERE TO_CHAR(date_field, 'YYYYMMDD') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1, 'YYYYMMDD');
```

**Some explanation**

*If you have a field that is not in date format but want to compare using date i.e. field is considered as date but in number format* e.g. 20190823 (YYYYMMDD)

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE ID_DATE = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

*If you have a field that is in date/timestamp format and you need to compare, Just change the  format*

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  FROM DUAL
```

IF you want to **return it to date format**

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS NEW_DATE  FROM DUAL
```

**Conclusion.**

With this knowledge you can convert the filed you want to compare to a YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD or any year-month-date format then compare with the same sysdate format.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT field,datetime_field 
FROM database
WHERE datetime_field > (CURRENT_DATE - 1)
```

Its been some time that I worked on Oracle. But, I think this should work.

Comment: CURRENT_DATE adds the time, I just want the date

Answer (score 2):

this

```
    SELECT field,datetime_field 
FROM database
WHERE datetime_field > (sysdate-1)
```

will work. The question is: is the 'datetime_field' has the same format as sysdate ? 
My way to handle that: use 'to_char()' function (only works in Oracle).

samples:
**previous day**:

```
select your_column
from your_table
where to_char(sysdate-1, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

*or*

```
select extract(day from date_field)||'/'|| 
       extract(month from date_field)||'/'||
       extract(year from date_field)||'/'||
as mydate
from dual(or a_table)
where extract(day from date_field) = an_int_number and
      extract(month from date_field) = an_int_number and so on..
```

**comparing date**:

```
select your_column
from your_table
where
to_char(a_datetime_column, 'dd.mm.yyyy') > or < or >= or <= to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

**time range** between yesterday and a day before yesterday:

```
select your_column
from your_table
where
to_char(a_datetime_column, 'dd.mm.yyyy') > or < or >= or <= to_char(sysdate-1, 'dd.mm.yyyy') and
to_char(a_datetime_column, 'dd.mm.yyyy') > or < or >= or <= to_char(sysdate-2, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

other **time range** *variation*

```
select your_column
from your_table
where 
to_char(a_datetime_column, 'dd.mm.yyyy') is between to_char(sysdate-1, 'dd.mm.yyyy') 
and to_char(sysdate-2, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also execute this command:

select (sysdate-1) PREVIOUS_DATE from dual;

Answer (score -1):

Im a bit confused about this part "TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')".
What were you trying to do with this clause ? 
The format that you are displaying in your result is the default format when you run the basic query of getting date from DUAL. 
Other than that, i did this in your query and it retrieved the previous day 
'SELECT (CURRENT_DATE - 1)  FROM Dual'. Do let me know if it works out for you and if not then do tell me about the problem. Thanks and all the best.